# I cannot execute this code

Tags: education

```
a= Format[primeFactorForm[n_Integer]] := Times @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] /. _[x_] :> x
block[n_Integer] := Join @@@ Array[{#, primeFactorForm@#} &[# + 100*#2] &, {100, 10}, {1 + (n - 1) 1000, 0}]
grid[m_?MatrixQ] := With[{th = AbsoluteThickness[1]}, Grid[m, Dividers -> ({#, #} &@{th, {True}, th})]]
Array[grid@block@# &, 8] // Scan[Print]
Export["C:\\abc\\table.pdf", a, "pdf"]
```

I cannot execute this code.

[image]

result of pdf file

Comment: The code executes for me using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 under Windows 8.1 (64x), although I did not do the `Export`

Comment: Works with version 10.0.1.0, Win7, 64-bit, too.
 Don't you have any error message?

Comment: You're exporting "a" to a PDF, but a is null. Try getting "a" in your notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign something to a, before exporting it.

Try this ...

```
primeFactorForm[n_Integer] := 
  Times @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] /. _[x_] :> x;

block[n_Integer] := 
  Join @@@ Array[{#, primeFactorForm@#} &[# + 100*#2] &, {100, 
     10}, {1 + (n - 1) 1000, 0}];

grid[m_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{th = AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
   Grid[m, Dividers -> ({#, #} &@{th, {True}, th})]];

a = Array[grid@block@# &, 8](*//Scan[Print]*);

Export["C:\\abc\\table.pdf", a, "pdf"]
```

Edit:
As an alternative to export, select our output and save it das PDF with "save selection as ...".

The images showes the differences between Mma, the PDF Export, and the export of the selection:
[image]

I think the problem with `Export[]` is the much too wide table.
Even Mma chooses the representation with the 3 points, if you downsize your window:
[image]

Comment: I developed a similar answer but found that `Export` did not faithfully reproduce the array.  What is your experience?

Comment: What do you mean with "did not faithfully reproduce the array"? My PDFs looks like the table in my notebook. With the exception of long numbers, which are splittet in more lines in the PDF.

Comment: That is what I meant.  The PDF font is larger, column widths are different, and text sometimes is split into multiple rows for columns 2, 4, 6, etc.  I tried to do better by using `Export` `pdf` options `ImageSize` and `ImageResolution` but without success.  I also tried directly saving the table from the notebook in PDF format, but the result was even worse.

Comment: @bbgodfrey select our output, then "save selection as..." PDF gives me a perfect result.

Comment: Our defaults must be different.  Such is life.